# Find which file has the issue from the below Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

**Problem Statement:-**
Below is the script that someone else wrote and he left the company so I don't know whom should I ask about this. So that is the reason I am posting here to find the solution.

What this script does is- It gzip the data from a particular folder `(/data/ds/real/EXPORT_v1x0)` for a particular date (20121017) and move it back to HDFS `(hdfs://ares-nn/apps/tech/ds/new/)` directory.

```
date=20121017
groups=(0 '1[0-3]' '1[^0-3]' '[^01]')
  for shard in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11; do
    for piece in 0 1 2 3; do
        group=${groups[$piece]}
        if ls -l /data/ds/real/EXPORT_v1x0_${date}_${shard}_T_${group}*.dat.gz; then
          gzip -dc /data/ds/real/EXPORT_v1x0_${date}_${shard}_T_${group}*.dat.gz | \
          hadoop jar /export/home/ds/lib/HadoopUtil.jar com.host.hadoop.platform.util.WriteToHDFS -z -u \
          hdfs://ares-nn/apps/tech/ds/new/$date/EXPORT-part-$shard-$piece
          sleep 15
       fi
    done
  done
```

So during the migration to HDFS I found out this file has some problem in HDFS-

```
hdfs://ares-nn/apps/tech/ds/new/20121017/EXPORT-part-8-3
```

So Is there any way by doing some permutation from the above script we can find out what are the files under this directory `(/data/ds/real/EXPORT_v1x0)` which ultimately got converted to this `hdfs://ares-nn/apps/tech/ds/new/20121017/EXPORT-part-8-3` which has the problem.

Any thoughts?

**Update:-**

Something like this below?

```
groups=(0 '1[0-3]' '1[^0-3]' '[^01]')
  for shard in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11; do
    for piece in 0 1 2 3; do
        group=${groups[$piece]}
        if ls -l /data/ds/real/EXPORT_v1x0_${date}_${shard}_T_${group}*.dat.gz; then
          [ "$date/EXPORT-part-$shard-$piece" == "20121017/EXPORT-part-8-3" ] && {
                echo /data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_${date}_${shard}_T_${group}*.dat.gz
            }
         fi
    done
  done
```

**Few Sample Files Format I have in the /data/real/EXPORT folder-**

```
/data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_20121017_4_T_115600_115800.dat.gz
/data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_20121017_4_T_235600_235800.dat.gz
/data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_20121017_4_T_115800_120000.dat.gz
/data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_20121017_4_T_235800_000000.dat.gz
```

And few sample output that I got after making changes-

```
/data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_20121017_0_T_0*.dat.gz: No such file or directory
/data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_20121017_0_T_1[0-3]*.dat.gz: No such file or directory
/data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_20121017_0_T_1[^0-3]*.dat.gz: No such file or directory
/data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_20121017_0_T_[^01]*.dat.gz: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It will be hard to help you. You wrote 'this file has some problem', but 'problem' can mean many things. If you suspect there was a decompression error, you should see the output. gzip should display the problem. If the data is the problem then you would need to remove everything after `|` in the `gzip -dc` line and replace it with a `grep` that will be looking for the 'problem'. I have no other idea what else could I suggest.

Comment: I understood what you said just now but my question is by doing some permuatation we can find out which file ultimately got converted to `hdfs://ares-nn/apps/tech/ds/new/20121017/EXPORT-part-8-3` right? As there are few for loops at the top from that we can get to know of this I guess. And that's what I need to know, so that I can manually add those files again after deleting the file that has some problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case reaplce the whole `gzip` line to:

```
[ "$date/EXPORT-part-$shard-$piece" == "20121017/EXPORT-part-8-3" ] && {
    echo /data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_${date}_${shard}_T_${group}*.dat.gz
}
```

That should do the trick.

Edit: remove `sleep` to speed up the loop!

Comment: I updated the question with the piece of code you asked me to add. Can you take a look whether I am doing right or not?

Comment: Yes, to mee looks right. It should echo file names used to generate hdfs://ares-nn/apps/tech/ds/new/20121017/EXPORT-part-8-3. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Didn't do the trick. But it printed out some statements showing as No Such File or Directory. I updated my question with few samples data in `/data/real/EXPORT directory`.

Comment: I see the format, but you are insterested in `20121017/EXPORT-part-8-3` which is a *result* name and not the *source* name. Now the question is why does it say "no such file or directory", and I suppose you have a script, let's say `a.sh`, and you called it `a.sh` instead of `./a.sh`. It's a guess only, though.

Comment: @Nevzz03: I will have to take off in a few moments, so let's focus, so we can solve it for you now.

Comment: Yes I ran like that. Let me clear one more thing- Some of the files starting with `/data/real/EXPORT_v1x0_20121017` will get converted to this `hdfs://ares-nn/apps/tech/ds/new/20121017/EXPORT-part-8-3` somehow. And that's what I need to find out which files got converted to that one. So that I can delete this hdfs file `hdfs://ares-nn/apps/tech/ds/new/20121017/EXPORT-part-8-3` because it has some problem and move the file again (which we can find out from your suggestion which is not working currently) to hdfs. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18547/discussion-between-grzegorz-and-nevzz03)